# How do I set the text of a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem with an image on it.  How do I set the text under the image either via IB or programmatically?

Thanks
Deshawn

Comment: are you sure you are talking about a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Yes, thats what I use to display an image for an actionable button.  Am I supposed to be using something else?

Comment: so, if it's a button with an image, where does the text come into play?

Comment: Well I want to add text to that image... without having to edit the image itself.  Maybe I can post my dilema a different way... how do I create a button with an image AND text such that when a user clicks on either of them, it fires my event?

Comment: it's the button that reacts to the touch, not the image.

Comment: Ok... how do I create a button that has BOTH an image and text?

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItem` has a `customView` property that you can use to customize the appearance of the item.